# Deploying Tensorflow Trained model on HoloLens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens, tensorflowsharp

I am developing an extension for an existing app for HoloLens that should use a model which was trained by tensorflow.

My attempt is to use TensorFlowSharp because the existing app is using unity (C#).

I build using:

> ```
> Scripting Runtime Version: .Net 4x or Equivalent
> Scripting Backend: IL2CPP
> API Compatibility Level: .Net Standard 2.0
> TensorflowSharp 1.7
> Tensorflow 1.7.1
> unity2018
> Windows 10
> libtensorflow.dll (build from windows 32bit, as hololens is in 32 bit)
> ```

My Question is what is this error and any idea how to solve it?

It seems like something happen in the IL2CPP backend but no extra information is given.

I have succeeded in building the apps with unity, however I get the error when I deploy it to hololens:

> ```
> Exception thrown at 0x77452D72 in TFSharpTest2018.exe: Microsoft C++ 
> exception: Il2CppExceptionWrapper at memory location 0x0E5FF36C.
> ```

Comment: TensorFlowSharp doesn't seem to be a good choice for serving TF models in C# programs in the future. The github page of the project recommends to use TensorFlow.NET instead. 
I used both, switched to TensorFlow.NET recently and it is closer to the python TF syntax, easier to deploy and seems to be more actively developed.

Comment: @EricFournie hi, thanks for the tip! i will check and test it out.

Comment: There are lots of examples available on https://tensorflownet.readthedocs.io but some of them use an older version of the API. If something doesn't work, check the examples in the source code instead of the online doc.